# Spark: Draw learning curve of a model with spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, machine-learning

I am using Spark and I would like to train a machine learning model.

Because of bad results, I would like to display the error made by the model at each epoch of the training (on train and test dataset).

I will then use this information to determined if my model is underfitting or overfitting the data.

**Question:** How can I draw the learning curve of a model with spark ?

In the following example, I have implement my own evaluator and override the evaluate method to print the metrics I was needed, but only two values have been display (maxIter = 1000).

MinimalRunnableCode.scala:

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.Vectors
import org.apache.spark.ml.regression.LinearRegression
import org.apache.spark.ml.tuning.{ParamGridBuilder, TrainValidationSplit}
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

object Min extends App {

  // Open spark session.
  val conf = new SparkConf()
    .setMaster("local")
    .set("spark.network.timeout", "800")

  val ss = SparkSession.builder
    .config(conf)
    .getOrCreate

  // Load data.
  val data = ss.createDataFrame(ss.sparkContext.parallelize(
      List(
        (Vectors.dense(1, 2), 1),
        (Vectors.dense(1, 3), 2),
        (Vectors.dense(1, 2), 1),
        (Vectors.dense(1, 3), 2),
        (Vectors.dense(1, 2), 1),
        (Vectors.dense(1, 3), 2),
        (Vectors.dense(1, 2), 1),
        (Vectors.dense(1, 3), 2),
        (Vectors.dense(1, 2), 1),
        (Vectors.dense(1, 3), 2),
        (Vectors.dense(1, 4), 3)
      )
    ))
    .withColumnRenamed("_1", "features")
    .withColumnRenamed("_2", "label")

  val Array(training, test) = data.randomSplit(Array(0.8, 0.2), seed = 42)

  // Create model of linear regression.
  val lr = new LinearRegression().setMaxIter(1000)

  // Create parameters grid that will be used to train different version of the linear model.
  val paramGrid = new ParamGridBuilder()
    .addGrid(lr.regParam, Array(0.001))
    .addGrid(lr.fitIntercept)
    .addGrid(lr.elasticNetParam, Array(0.5))
    .build()

  // Create trainer using validation split to evaluate which set of parameters performs the best.
  val trainValidationSplit = new TrainValidationSplit()
    .setEstimator(lr)
    .setEvaluator(new CustomRegressionEvaluator)
    .setEstimatorParamMaps(paramGrid)
    .setTrainRatio(0.8) // 80% of the data will be used for training and the remaining 20% for validation.

  // Run train validation split, and choose the best set of parameters.
  var model = trainValidationSplit.fit(training)

  // Close spark session.
  ss.stop()
}
```

CustomRegressionEvaluator.scala:

```
import org.apache.spark.ml.evaluation.{Evaluator, RegressionEvaluator}
import org.apache.spark.ml.param.{Param, ParamMap, Params}
import org.apache.spark.ml.util.{DefaultParamsReadable, DefaultParamsWritable, Identifiable}
import org.apache.spark.mllib.evaluation.RegressionMetrics
import org.apache.spark.sql.{Dataset, Row}
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._

final class CustomRegressionEvaluator (override val uid: String) extends Evaluator with HasPredictionCol with HasLabelCol with DefaultParamsWritable {

  def this() = this(Identifiable.randomUID("regEval"))

  def checkNumericType(
                        schema: StructType,
                        colName: String,
                        msg: String = ""): Unit = {
    val actualDataType = schema(colName).dataType
    val message = if (msg != null && msg.trim.length > 0) " " + msg else ""
    require(actualDataType.isInstanceOf[NumericType], s"Column $colName must be of type " +
      s"NumericType but was actually of type $actualDataType.$message")
  }

  def checkColumnTypes(
                        schema: StructType,
                        colName: String,
                        dataTypes: Seq[DataType],
                        msg: String = ""): Unit = {
    val actualDataType = schema(colName).dataType
    val message = if (msg != null && msg.trim.length > 0) " " + msg else ""
    require(dataTypes.exists(actualDataType.equals),
      s"Column $colName must be of type equal to one of the following types: " +
        s"${dataTypes.mkString("[", ", ", "]")} but was actually of type $actualDataType.$message")
  }

  var i = 0 // count the number of time the evaluate method is called
  override def evaluate(dataset: Dataset[_]): Double = {
    val schema = dataset.schema
    checkColumnTypes(schema, $(predictionCol), Seq(DoubleType, FloatType))
    checkNumericType(schema, $(labelCol))

    val predictionAndLabels = dataset
      .select(col($(predictionCol)).cast(DoubleType), col($(labelCol)).cast(DoubleType))
      .rdd
      .map { case Row(prediction: Double, label: Double) => (prediction, label) }
    val metrics = new RegressionMetrics(predictionAndLabels)
    val metric = "mae" match {
      case "rmse" => metrics.rootMeanSquaredError
      case "mse" => metrics.meanSquaredError
      case "r2" => metrics.r2
      case "mae" => metrics.meanAbsoluteError
    }
    println(s"$i $metric") // Print the metrics
    i = i + 1 // Update counter
    metric
  }

  override def copy(extra: ParamMap): RegressionEvaluator = defaultCopy(extra)
}

object RegressionEvaluator extends DefaultParamsReadable[RegressionEvaluator] {

  override def load(path: String): RegressionEvaluator = super.load(path)
}

private[ml] trait HasPredictionCol extends Params {

  /**
    * Param for prediction column name.
    * @group param
    */
  final val predictionCol: Param[String] = new Param[String](this, "predictionCol", "prediction column name")

  setDefault(predictionCol, "prediction")

  /** @group getParam */
  final def getPredictionCol: String = $(predictionCol)
}

private[ml] trait HasLabelCol extends Params {

  /**
    * Param for label column name.
    * @group param
    */
  final val labelCol: Param[String] = new Param[String](this, "labelCol", "label column name")

  setDefault(labelCol, "label")

  /** @group getParam */
  final def getLabelCol: String = $(labelCol)
}
```

Comment: You can't draw with Spark but you can always collect those metrics and use your favorite plotting lib to do it.

Comment: Can your explain how to collect these metrics ?

Comment: I thought you had the values already. spark-ml "learning" process doesn't provide that. You ought setting your learning hyper parameters then record those metrics. I know the learning process will take longer but this is how it works with Spark. Not to mention the CrossValidator ofc https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-tuning.html#model-selection-aka-hyperparameter-tuning

Comment: Ok, I understand that. But I can't find out which code is called at the end of each training iteration. I have tryied to create my own Evaluator in which I have override the evalute method (to print these metrics). But, I got something like 2 values even if the maxIter is set to 1000. Should I concluded that only two iterations of training have been running ? How can I force spark to run n training iterations ?

Comment: I can't tell like that, you'll need to provide an [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I just to add a MVCE on the question, hope that will help !

Comment: There is actually a conceptual misunderstanding here. You need to re-implement the algorithm and not the evaluator. What's happening here is that you have 2 sets of parameters being examined (cf. your ParamGrid) thus you have two values being shown.

Comment: That's what I missed ! Thank you, I will try it :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is a possible solution for the specific case of `LinearRegression` and any other algorithm that support *objective history* (in this case, And `LinearRegressionTrainingSummary` does the job).

Let's first create a *minimal verifiable and complete example* :

```
import org.apache.spark.ml.param.ParamMap
import org.apache.spark.ml.regression.{LinearRegression, LinearRegressionModel}
import org.apache.spark.ml.tuning.{ParamGridBuilder, TrainValidationSplit}
import org.apache.spark.mllib.util.{LinearDataGenerator, MLUtils}
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

val spark: SparkSession = SparkSession.builder().getOrCreate()

import org.apache.spark.ml.evaluation.RegressionEvaluator
import spark.implicits._

val data = {
  val tmp = LinearDataGenerator.generateLinearRDD(
    spark.sparkContext,
    nexamples = 10000,
    nfeatures = 4,
    eps = 0.05
  ).toDF

  MLUtils.convertVectorColumnsToML(tmp, "features")
}
```

As you've noticed, when you want to generate data for testing purposes for `spark-mllib` or `spark-ml`, it's advised to use data generators.

Now, let's train a linear regressor :

```
// Create model of linear regression.
val lr = new LinearRegression().setMaxIter(1000)

// The following line will create two sets of parameters
val paramGrid = new ParamGridBuilder().addGrid(lr.regParam, Array(0.001)).addGrid(lr.fitIntercept).addGrid(lr.elasticNetParam, Array(0.5)).build()

// Create trainer using validation split to evaluate which set of parameters performs the best.
// I'm using the regular RegressionEvaluator here
val trainValidationSplit = new TrainValidationSplit()
  .setEstimator(lr)
  .setEvaluator(new RegressionEvaluator)
  .setEstimatorParamMaps(paramGrid)
  .setTrainRatio(0.8) // 80% of the data will be used for training and the remaining 20% for validation.

// To retrieve subModels, make sure to set collectSubModels to true before fitting.
trainValidationSplit.setCollectSubModels(true)
// Run train validation split, and choose the best set of parameters.
var model = trainValidationSplit.fit(data)
```

Now since our model is trained, all we need is to get the objective history.

The following part needs a bit of gymnastics between the model and sub-models object parameters.

In case you have a `Pipeline` or so, this code needs to be modified, so use it carefully. It's just an example :

```
val objectiveHist = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(
  model.subModels.zip(model.getEstimatorParamMaps).map {
    case (m: LinearRegressionModel, pm: ParamMap) =>
      val history: Array[Double] = m.summary.objectiveHistory
      val idx: Seq[Int] = 1 until history.length
      // regParam, elasticNetParam, fitIntercept
      val parameters = pm.toSeq.map(pair => (pair.param.name, pair.value.toString)) match {
        case Seq(x, y, z) => (x._2, y._2, z._2)
      }
      (parameters._1, parameters._2, parameters._3, idx.zip(history).toMap)
  }).toDF("regParam", "elasticNetParam", "fitIntercept", "objectiveHistory")
```

We can now examine those metrics :

```
objectiveHist.show(false)
// +--------+---------------+------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
// |regParam|elasticNetParam|fitIntercept|objectiveHistory                                                                                       |
// +--------+---------------+------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
// |0.001   |0.5            |true        |[1 -> 0.4999999999999999, 2 -> 0.4038796441909531, 3 -> 0.02659222058006269, 4 -> 0.026592220340980147]|
// |0.001   |0.5            |false       |[1 -> 0.5000637621421942, 2 -> 0.4039303922115196, 3 -> 0.026592220673025396, 4 -> 0.02659222039347222]|
// +--------+---------------+------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

You can notice that the training process actually stops after 4 iterations.

If you want just the number of iterations, you can do the following instead :

```
val objectiveHist2 = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(
  model.subModels.zip(model.getEstimatorParamMaps).map {
    case (m: LinearRegressionModel, pm: ParamMap) =>
      val history: Array[Double] = m.summary.objectiveHistory
      // regParam, elasticNetParam, fitIntercept
      val parameters = pm.toSeq.map(pair => (pair.param.name, pair.value.toString)) match {
        case Seq(x, y, z) => (x._2, y._2, z._2)
      }
      (parameters._1, parameters._2, parameters._3, history.size)
  }).toDF("regParam", "elasticNetParam", "fitIntercept", "iterations")
```

I've changed the number of features in the generator (`nfeatures = 100`) for the sake of demonstrations :

```
objectiveHist2.show
// +--------+---------------+------------+----------+
// |regParam|elasticNetParam|fitIntercept|iterations|
// +--------+---------------+------------+----------+
// |   0.001|            0.5|        true|        11|
// |   0.001|            0.5|       false|        11|
// +--------+---------------+------------+----------+
```

Comment: This was really good, I was able to do something similar in Python. However, in the Objective History we are provided one set of values for each param combo, which I assume gives us the cost function value at each iteration on the training set. But if we want to draw learning curves to infer bias vs overfitting, shouldn't we be getting two Objective History sequences fo values: one for training and one for validation set?

Answer (score 0):

In case you just came from Databricks I leave here my code to use in a Databricks Notebook and using PySpark. It is just an adaptation from [eliasah](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3415409/eliasah)'s code.

```py
from pyspark.ml.regression import (
    LinearRegression,
    LinearRegressionModel,
    LinearRegressionTrainingSummary,
)
from pyspark.ml.regression import FMRegressor, FMRegressionModel
from pyspark.ml.tuning import ParamGridBuilder, TrainValidationSplit
from pyspark.mllib.util import LinearDataGenerator, MLUtils
from pyspark.ml.param import Params
from pyspark.ml.evaluation import RegressionEvaluator
from pyspark import pandas

# Generate data
dfdata = LinearDataGenerator.generateLinearRDD(
    spark.sparkContext, nexamples=10_000, nfeatures=3, eps=0.25
).toDF()

dfdataML = MLUtils.convertVectorColumnsToML(dfdata, "features")

# Create model of linear regression.
linear_regressor = LinearRegression(maxIter=1_000)

# The following line will create two sets of parameters
parameter_grid = (
    ParamGridBuilder()
    .baseOn({linear_regressor.labelCol: "label"})
    .baseOn([linear_regressor.predictionCol, "predicted"])
    .addGrid(linear_regressor.regParam, [0.001])
    .addGrid(linear_regressor.fitIntercept, [True, False])
    .addGrid(linear_regressor.elasticNetParam, [0.5, 0.1])
    .build()
)

regression_evaluator = RegressionEvaluator(
    labelCol="label", predictionCol="predicted", metricName="rmse"
)

# Create trainer using validation split to evaluate which set of parameters performs the best.
# I'm using the regular RegressionEvaluator here

train_validation_split = TrainValidationSplit(
    estimator=linear_regressor,
    evaluator=regression_evaluator,
    estimatorParamMaps=parameter_grid,
    trainRatio=0.8,  # 80% training 20% validation
    collectSubModels=True,  # To get all trained models during gridsearch
    seed=42,
    parallelism=1,
)

# Run grid search training
trained_grid_search = train_validation_split.fit(dfdataML)

parameter_grid = trained_grid_search.getEstimatorParamMaps()
models = trained_grid_search.subModels

results = list()
for params, model in zip(parameter_grid, models):
    pdict = {p.name:v for p, v in params.items() if p.name not in ['labelCol','predictionCol']}
    group = str(pdict)
    pdict.update({'group':group})

    for iteration, cost in enumerate(model.summary.objectiveHistory):
        d = pdict.copy()
        d.update({'it':iteration, 'cost':cost})
        results.append(d)

dfresults = pandas.DataFrame(results).to_spark()
```

[image]